# Cannot force zorder with basemap and quiver

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I cannot force the zorder for an overplot with matplolib basemap and the quiver.

Here is what I am doing (Mac OsX, python 3.6)

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latmin = -33.496886
latmax = -33.388023
lonmin = -70.692902
lonmax = -70.515747

map_s = Basemap(projection = 'merc', epsg=4326, llcrnrlat=latmin, urcrnrlat=latmax,
                llcrnrlon=lonmin, urcrnrlon=lonmax, lat_ts=20, resolution='i')
map_s.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D',
                  xpixels=200, verbose=True)

x, y, u, v = -70.564464625, -52.011810175, -0.2569774, -0.1781287
lon, lat = map_s(float(x), float(y))
map_s.quiver(lon, lat, float(u), float(v), width=0.005, scale_units='xy',
             scale=1, color='r', zorder=100)

plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.show()
```

When I do this, the satellite image is above the red vector while I wish to see the opposite, having the red vector on top of the satellite image.

I have also tried to do (ex1)

```
plt.quiver(lon, lat, float(u), float(v), width=0.005, scale_units='xy',
             scale=1, color='r', zorder=100)
```

instead of (ex2)

```
map_s.quiver(lon, lat, float(u), float(v), width=0.005, scale_units='xy',
             scale=1, color='r', zorder=100)
```

but the result is the same. What am I missing, what am I doing wrong?

(Minor question: When I remove the part

```
map_s.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D',
                  xpixels=200, verbose=True)
```

I can see the vector when I do (ex1) but not (ex2). Should it be the case)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plot location of quiver arrow is out of bound, and its size is too big.
Zorder is not relevant, the default value is fine.
Here is the code that adjust the position and size of the arrow to plot within the image limits.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latmin = -33.496886
latmax = -33.388023
lonmin = -70.692902
lonmax = -70.515747

map_s = Basemap(projection = 'merc', epsg=4326, llcrnrlat=latmin, urcrnrlat=latmax,
                llcrnrlon=lonmin, urcrnrlon=lonmax, lat_ts=20, resolution='i')
map_s.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D',
                  xpixels=200, verbose=True)

# Out of limits x,y,u,v=-70.5644,-52.0118,-0.2569,-0.1781
x, y, u, v = -70.55, -33.4, -0.05, -0.05

lon, lat = map_s(float(x), float(y))
map_s.quiver(lon, lat, float(u), float(v), width=0.005, scale_units='xy',
             scale=1, color='r')

plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You will have to decide which to adjust, the image limits or the quiver's.

Comment: Absolutely, you were right. I completely missed that. Thanks a lot!